# Printing and searching python namespaces from rospy.get_param()

Tags: ros, python, rospy, nxt-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am catkin-izing, updating, and making revisions to the nxt ROS packages. I have hit an issue that seems basic but I could use some help to get through it. Searches for accessing Python dictionaries haven't helped much.

The code:

```
host = rospy.get_param("~host", None)
sock = nxt.locator.find_one_brick(host)
b = sock.connect()

config = rospy.get_param("~"+ns)
components = []
for c in config:
    rospy.loginfo("Creating %s with name %s on %s",c['type'],c['name'],c['port'])
    if c['type'] == 'motor':
        components.append(Motor(c, b))
    elif c['type'] == 'touch':
        components.append(TouchSensor(c, b))
    elif c['type'] == 'ultrasonic':
        components.append(UltraSonicSensor(c, b))
    elif c['type'] == 'color':
        components.append(ColorSensor(c, b))
    elif c['type'] == 'intensity':
        components.append(IntensitySensor(c, b))
    elif c['type'] == 'gyro':
        components.append(GyroSensor(c, b))
    elif c['type'] == 'accelerometer':
        components.append(AccelerometerSensor(c, b))
    else:
        rospy.logerr('Invalid sensor/actuator type %s'%c['type'])
```

My issue is with the `c['text']` in the for loop. When I `print config[c]` it prints the value of the key. Printing 'c' alone prints the key. However, when `c['text']` is called ROS fires back an error:

```
TypeError: string indices must be intergers, not str
```

The namespace (returned into the config variable) can have several sensors set up by a .yaml file.

Thank you for your time.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228737/printing-and-searching-python-namespaces-from-rospy.get_param()/) by [Derkabub](https://answers.ros.org/users/22839/derkabub/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-03-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [eric-wieser](https://answers.ros.org/users/26065/eric-wieser/) on 2016-03-11**:
What does `print(config)` give you?

**Comment by [eric-wieser](https://answers.ros.org/users/26065/eric-wieser/) on 2016-03-11**:
Where is the official source for the nxt packages? The source link on the wiki page is dead

**Comment by [Derkabub](https://answers.ros.org/users/22839/derkabub/) on 2016-03-11**:
I am not sure how to report the source link being broken issue. There is more on this at sig/NXT. Between the ros wiki and the sig/NXT I figured out indiviuals working with this and selected a repository to grab the variant of ros nxt.

**Comment by [Derkabub](https://answers.ros.org/users/22839/derkabub/) on 2016-03-11**:
As for your previous comment: If I use rospy.loginfo() to print 'config' to screen it prints the entire dictionary, which in my case only pertains to one sensor or a single dictonary. There are several sensors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`for c in config` iterates over the keys of the config, not the values. I think you want:

```
host = rospy.get_param("~host", None)
sock = nxt.locator.find_one_brick(host)
b = sock.connect()

config = rospy.get_param("~"+ns)
components = []
for k, c in config.items():
    # do something with k - it might be useful
    rospy.loginfo("Creating %s with name %s on %s",c['type'],c['name'],c['port'])
    if c['type'] == 'motor':
        components.append(Motor(c, b))
    elif c['type'] == 'touch':
        components.append(TouchSensor(c, b))
    elif c['type'] == 'ultrasonic':
        components.append(UltraSonicSensor(c, b))
    elif c['type'] == 'color':
        components.append(ColorSensor(c, b))
    elif c['type'] == 'intensity':
        components.append(IntensitySensor(c, b))
    elif c['type'] == 'gyro':
        components.append(GyroSensor(c, b))
    elif c['type'] == 'accelerometer':
        components.append(AccelerometerSensor(c, b))
    else:
        rospy.logerr('Invalid sensor/actuator type %s'%c['type'])
```

---

Originally posted by [eric-wieser](https://answers.ros.org/users/26065/eric-wieser/) with karma: 111 on 2016-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0